# Coalesce function - Date Difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datediff

I have a column called LOA Signature date and another one call Signed Date.

I am trying to find a formula that calculates the difference in months from the LOA Signature date to Today (In case LOA signature Date is blank, then the formula needs to use Signed Date)

Ageing = DATEDIF(TODAY()-"LOA Signature date and if blank, Signed Date"...

I created this formula for my PowerBI report but I don't know how to use same formula in Excell...any tip?

BL Months = DATEDIFF(coalesce('Weekly Slippage'[LOA Signature Date], 'Weekly Slippage'[Signed]), TODAY(), MONTH)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `=DATEDIF(IF(LOA_Sig_Date<>"",LOA_Sig_Date,Signed_Date),TODAY(),"M")`

Comment: Few sample will help us to understand your question better.

Comment: Thanks.Tried=DATEDIF(IF(ISBLANK(AU2),AT2,AU2),TODAY(),"M") and it worked                    AU = LOA Date and AT =Signed Date